# Barcode Scan With Both Hard and Soft Trigger EMDK

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

We have a custom scanner to scan barcode using, which works with SOFT trigger (Using App Button) by using Motorola's emdk library.

```
barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager) this.emdkManager.getInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);  
scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);  
scanner.addStatusListener(articleListener);  
scanner.addDataListener(new Scanner.DataListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {  
        processData(scanDataCollection);  
    }  
});  
scanner.addDataListener(dataListener);  
scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.SOFT_ALWAYS;  
scanner.enable();
```

How can i have both soft and Hard trigger to scan the data?
and with datalistener process the data received from both?

Answer (score 2):

Zebra Technologies acquire Motorola Solution enterprise business in Oct. 2014, most of the updated documentation is now available under the [Zebra Launchpad](http://developer.zebra.com).

`Scanner.TriggerType` controls how you want to activate the barcode scanner on Zebra Android devices, usually you can set it up or Hard (scan is activated pressing the hardware trigger button) or Soft (scan is activated as soon as you call the `Scanner.read()` method).
To have an application that can use the Hardware trigger and having an on screen button to activate the scanner you can leave set the triggerType to `Scanner.TriggerType.HARD` and implement a login in the click event handler for the *soft scan* button so that you set the TriggerType to `Scanner.TriggerType.SOFT_ONCE` and then you call the `Scanner.read()` method. You can eventually check if there's another read active.
This is a sample implementation that you can test adding a button in the [Barcode API sample included in the EMDK for Android (latest is v4.0)](http://zebra.github.io/emdk-for-android/4-0/samples/barcode/):

```
private void softScan() {
    if (scanner != null) {
        try {
            // Reset continuous flag
            bContinuousMode = false;
            if (scanner.isReadPending()) {
                // Cancel the pending read.
                scanner.cancelRead();
            }
            scanner.triggerType = TriggerType.SOFT_ONCE;
            scanner.read();

            new AsyncUiControlUpdate().execute(true);
        } catch (ScannerException e) {
            textViewStatus.setText("Status: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

So, usually you work with a `TriggerType.HARD`, but when you press the **SCAN** button you disable any pending read and you switch to `TriggerType.SCAN_ONCE`.
The implementation of the status listener needs to switch back the scanner to `TriggerType.HARD` and call the `read()` method.

You can find a complete sample at this [github repository](https://github.com/pfmaggi/Hard_Soft_Trigger) where I've added a `Soft Scan` button to the standard Zebra's EMDK Barcode API sample.

[image]

All the data are received by the same Data Listener.

Comment: what is `bContinuousMode` for? also `AsyncUiControlUpdate()` is it mandatory?. Unfortunately this is not working for me.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, as I wrote, this function fit into Zebra's EMDK v4.0 Barcode API sample. `bContinousMode` is a flag in the sample app that reactivate the Scanner as soon as a barcode has been read. The `AsyncUIControlUpdate()` is necessary because callback coming from the Barcode API are not guarantee to be on the UI thread.

Comment: Also, in case any Xamarin Developers are looking for this same sample in Xamarin, it can be found here http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-2/samples/barcode/. The nuget package has also been ported fairly recently from being a Xamarin componenent and is available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Symbol.XamarinEMDK#

Comment: Note that the sample I linked to is for Xamarin-Android.